# Display alert 7 days before event on first monday of every month

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a website where a scheduled event takes place on the first monday of every month.

I am in need of displaying a message on our home page that will start showing up a week before the event and continue to display until the date/time of the event.

I am sure there are a few ways to do this, just wondering if anybody has anything that has worked for them.

Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried? what are you thinking? show us some code, even if it is pseudo code - btw cron is *definitely not* the way to do this.

Comment: @Drixson, why would I use cron for a front end message. That makes zero sense.

Comment: @Yokhannan makes no sense also when you didn't show your relevant code.

Comment: "Seven days before the first Monday of the month" is logically equivalent to the much simpler statement "Last Monday of the month"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to test that the current date is in the interval of 7 days before the first Monday of the month. We also have to test two cases : suppose we are today in month X, the first Monday of the month may be in the month X or X +1.

I would do something like that :

```
<?php
if(
    (time() <= strtotime('first monday') && 
     time() >= strtotime('first monday - 7 days'))
    || (time() <= strtotime('first monday + 1 months') 
       && time() >= strtotime('first monday + 1 months - 7 days'))
) {
    echo 'Display your message';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Seven days before the first Monday of the month

is logically equivalent to the much simpler statement:

> Last Monday of the month

Because, in your case, that date is occurring in the future.

Which you can get via:

```
strtotime("last monday of this month");
```

You can also do something like:

```
strtotime("last monday of october 2013");
strtotime("last monday of last month");
```

Comment: I think your answer is good if we want to display a message exactly 7 days before the first monday of the month. But if we want to display it during the seven days after the last monday, in a reverse logical order as you suggest, I think it's getting more complicated to implement and keep it understandable.

Comment: @tomahim I think you guys are really just making "first and last Monday of the month" much more logically obscure than they really have to be.